# How to upload multiple image in database using laravel api

Tags: laravel

I want to insert multiple image in this code , please help me how to insert multiple images in this code..

**BlogController.php**

```
 public function storeBlog(Request $request)
    { 
         $blogs = new Blog($request->input()) ;

         $blogs->title = $request->title;
         $blogs->blog = $request->blog;

          if($file = $request->hasFile('image')) {

            $file = $request->file('image') ;

            $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName() ;
            $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/' ;
            $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);

            $blogs->image = '/images/'.$fileName ;
        }
         $blogs->save();

        return  $blogs;
    }
```

Comment: How to use foreach loop in this code please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this

```
if($request->hasFile('images'))
{    
   $data = [];
   foreach($request->file('images') as $image)
   {
      $fileName = $image->getClientOriginalName();
      $destinationPath = public_path().'/images/' ;
      $file->move($destinationPath,$fileName);

      $data[] = '/images/'.$fileName;
   }
 $blogs->image =  json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: its called undefined variable data..@Mehran

Comment: @Er.Dinesh answer updated. Please check let me know. :)

Comment: @Er.Dinesh upvote the answer if it works for you thanks. :)